# Why is using accounts.ui.config crashing my app?

Tags: meteor

Code (as suggested in the [ui-config documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_ui_config)
):

```
Accounts.ui.config({
  passwordSignupFields: 'USERNAME_AND_OPTIONAL_EMAIL'
});


Error: TypeError: Cannot call method 'config' of undefined
```

Comment: i had the same error a while ago, the problem was that i was calling the method on a server side script. Its a client side method, where do you call it ?

Comment: I am calling it in client.js. Thanks for the response.

Comment: I've created the file client/config.js and put the code there but still receive the error, any idea?

Comment: Add accounts-ui package

Answer (score 5):

I figured out that the file created in your project (yourprojectname.js) is the client script. My problem was that I created a new file called "client.js", although I didn't have to do that. Stupid me!

Hopefully this will be help for to someone else.

Comment: Yeah they should change the documentation to be clear it's for client side.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a client folder for client files it will work to add it there.  I just added it to a config.js file I added in my Client folder and it works fine.

client/config.js

`Accounts.ui.config({
  passwordSignupFields: 'USERNAME_AND_OPTIONAL_EMAIL'
});`